# Working with dropdownlistbox in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am using dropdownlist and one label in my html page. I want to change name of label 
on selection of my dropdownlist box. How is it possible?

pls povide any help for me .

Comment: where you are providing your code?

Comment: i am using simple html page <select name="selectcity">
<option>Mumbai</option><option>Delhi</option>
</select><label name="citylabel"></label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mXUdm/).

It will change the attribute 'name' of your label, and its text content (reading its new name attribute value) to see the change in effect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(select) {

  var value =  select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var label =  document.getElementById('mylabel');

  label.setAttribute('name', value);
  label.innerHTML = label.getAttribute('name');

} 
</script>

<select name="selectcity" onchange="changeValue(this);" >
    <option>Mumbai</option>
    <option>Delhi</option>
</select>
You selected: <label id="mylabel" name="citylabel"></label>
```

Comment: I'm glad! remember to accept the answer you find the most useful and correct.

Comment: sir, i also want to change image on selection of dropdown list box. pls provide any help

Comment: Then you should ask another specific question, since this one was about dropdown list. I will be glad to help you then :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <select id='derp' onchange="changeVal(this,'changeme');">  <!-- declare select, set onchange to point to changeVal JS -->
        <option value='test'>test</option>
    </select>
    <input id='changeme' />
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function changeVal(el,changeElID){

            var changeEl = document.getElementById(changeElID); // Get input to change
            changeEl.value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value; // Change input value to value of selected index

        }
    </script>
```

[EDIT]
re-reading the question it sounds like you are trying to change the name of the input box...if that is the case, change `changeEl.value` to `changeEl.name`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="all" border="0" id="gvLanguage">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <select id="ddlLanguage" style="width: 230px;">
                <option value="0">[Select]</option>
                <option value="1">Afrikaans</option>
                <option value="2">Akan</option>
                <option value="3">Albanian</option>
                <option value="4">American</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Selected Value: <label id="lblChange" ></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ddlLanguage").change(function(){
        var vSelectedValue  = $("option:selected",$(this)).text();
       $("#lblChange").text(vSelectedValue);
    });
});
```

[**CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/owusos)

Comment: thanks sir , for your help but i am not understading what does means of doller sign in simple html

Comment: The OP is not asking for jQuery, but for plain javascript implementation. The dollar sign refers to the usage of a library called jQuery, which makes javascript development less tedious.

Comment: @Sandeep: actually $ sign is a jQuery symbol if u choose jQuery for JavaScript development.i think u don't know about jQuery but I'll prefer you to learn jQuery and use it for client side development because of its features like cross-browser compatibility,require less code than JavaScript and many more but final choice is yours.